# Как добавить текст index в swiper js к bullets

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper

Подскажите пожалуйста, задача следующая. По мимо добавления класса к буллету swiper js, необходимо в сам 'span' записывать index буллета. Возможно ли это реализовать?

```
renderBullet: (index, className) => {
    return `<span class='${className} feature-pagination${index}'> </span>`;
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничто не мешает ещё раз использовать переменную *index*:

```js
renderBullet: (index, className) => {
    return `<span class='${className} feature-pagination${index}'>${index}</span>`;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
renderBullet: (index, className) => {
    return `<span class='${className} feature-pagination${index+=1}'>${index+=1}</span>`;
    },
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]